How to define variable in dynamic SQL in IBM Db2?
In Db2 v11.5 on Linux I would like to create variable and then use this variable in SELECT statement. I don't want to create procedure or function on database, I just want to do this in dynamic SQL from db2cmd or some database tool.
Simplified sample:
BEGIN
     DECLARE name VARCHAR(10);
     SET name = 'John';
     SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WHERE name = :name;
END;


EDIT:
Why I don't want to create stored procedure/function? I perform audit every half a year for database privileges/authorizations on several databases and I don't have create procedure privilege on some of the databases, because of strict security settings. In most cases I only have access to system catalog tables which is perfectly enough I can create audit. I list database users and then for "suspicious" users I perform full permission/authority checks executing several SQL-s from system catalog. Up till now for every user I have used text editor and used find/replace, which is OK solution, but variable is better solution. Thanks!

Your question shows use of :variable-name but that syntax is only available either in embedded-SQL, or in Oracle mode (if enabled for your Db2-Instance and Db2-database).
Also some client-side tooling (from third parties) allow for scripting with variables, but it works only when using those specific tools, i.e will not work with the Db2-CLP.
In general, creating routines (user defined functions or stored procedures) are a wiser choice. It is unclear why you want to avoid that option.
You can either use global variables (easier, fewer restrictions, but all the disadvantages of global variables), or you can use anonymous-blocks (many restrictions in Db2).
But anonymous blocks will not let you directly see the output of a SELECT, you'd need to do the SELECT outside of the block. IBM documents various restrictions on what is possible with compound-sql(inlined), refer to the documentation in the Db2 Knowledge Centre for details.
With global variables ( this example uses the Db2 CLP on linux ):
create or replace variable g_name varchar(1024);

set g_name = 'TABLES';

select tabschema from syscat.tables where tabname = g_name order by 1 with ur;

With compound-sql(inlined) anonymous block (with the Db2 CLP on linux) here is one way to do it (other ways are possible) with session tables:
--#SET TERMINATOR @

set serveroutput on@

declare global temporary table session.my_results(name varchar(1024))
  with replace on commit preserve rows@

BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(10);
     DECLARE v_numrows INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     SET v_name = 'TABLES';
     insert into session.my_results(name) 
         select tabschema from syscat.tables 
         where tabname = v_name;
     get diagnostics v_numrows = row_count;
     call dbms_output.put_line('Number of rows inserted  is = '||char(v_numrows));
     
END
@
select substr(name, 1, 20) as tabschema from session.my_results order by 1@


I have used first option, it is simple and works perfectly.
